# NLP // Create vector representation of words using 'count-based' model

Tags: python, vector, nlp

So I know most people use prediction/regression models now like GloVe or word2vec, and creating vectors using the count-based model should actually be simpler, but I'm having a difficult time figuring it out (I think because I don't have much background in programming).

Basically, I want to create vector representations of English words, and I want to be able to set the dimensions for each vector (which will probably be something like the 2,000 most frequent words in whatever corpus I end up using). I also want to be able to set the window (for instance, look at x number of words before and after the target word).

What would be the best way to get started doing this (preferably using python)?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm too dense, but I can't figure out from this how I would set up the dimensions for the vectors or set up the window

Comment: do you just want to create an array/vector of word counts? when you say 'each vector', what does each mean? What should a vector represent for you?

Comment: @AbtPst I want to download a corpus, find the 2,000 most frequent words (excluding stop words) and use those as the dimensions for the vector representations. Then I want to go through the same corpus, and select a window, say five words before each target word and five words after, and use the frequencies of how often each target word appears in the same window as a context word (one of the 2,000 most frequent). I want to use pointwise mutual info for weighting. So I want to end up with a txt file where each word is followed by 2,000 numbers, each representing one of those 2000

Comment: Perhaps scikit-learn is the best way to do that, but I can't figure out how to set up a window or employ pointwise mutual infomation